# a triangle problem of angles

Tags: triangles

suppose in triangle ABC , angle of BAC is 60 degree. 
if K is intersection point of [CM] median(for segment[AB] )and [BN] altitude.
 also suppose |KM|=1 cm and |CK|=6 cm calculate angels of triangle ABC?

[image]

Comment: could you show a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first: we suppose $BN=x+y$and $AC=z$,$NC=w$, $BM=a$ and angle $ACM=\gamma$

we have in triangle $BKM$ by $\cos$

law: $1=a^2+y^2-\sqrt3ay$ then $$y=\frac{\sqrt3a +(or -)\sqrt{4-a^2}}{2}$$

$y>x$ then  $$y=\frac{\sqrt3a + \sqrt{4-a^2}}{2}$$ . 
in (right angle)triangle $ABN$ :$\sin 60=\frac{y+x}{2a}$ then $y+x=\sqrt3a$ ($IV$) so $x=\frac{\sqrt3a -\sqrt{4-a^2}}{2}$ ($III$)
we have in triangle $AMC$ by  $\sin$
 law : $$\frac{\sin A}{7}=\frac{\sin \gamma}{a}$$ then $$\sin\gamma=\frac{\sqrt3a}{14}$$ ($I$)
in (right angle) triangle $NKC$: $\sin \gamma=\frac{x}{6}$($II$) then by($II$) and($I$) and ($III$)

we have : $$\frac{a\sqrt3-\sqrt{4-a^2}}{2*6}=\frac{a\sqrt3}{14}$$ so $196-49a^2=3a^2$ then $a=\frac{7}{\sqrt{13}}$($VI$)

we have in triangle $AMC$ by $\cos$ law: $49=a^2+z^2-az$ so $z^2-az+z^2-49=0$ then

$$z=\frac{a+\sqrt{196-3a^2}}{2}$$   ( $$z=\frac{a-\sqrt{196-3a^2}}{2}$$ is not 
acceptable because $A=60$ in 
(right angle)triangle $ABN$ then $\cos 60 =\frac{z-w}{2a}$ then $z=a+w$).

so $$w=\frac{\sqrt{196-3a^2}-a}{2} $$($V$).

in (right angle) triangle $BNC$ : $\tan C=\frac{x+y}{w}$ then by($V$)and($IV$) :

$\tan C = \frac{2\sqrt3a}{\sqrt{196-3a^2}-a}$ so by ($VI$) :

$\tan C=\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$ so    $C=30$   and   $B=90$

Comment: I can't make sense of your answer. It will be much more feasible if you format the math correctly. A tutorial can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you for usefull help. Daryl